# I'm having trouble retrieving data from a url using ajax and jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a jquery function which calls a url. When I get to this url it returns a value (it uses the mvc architecture). This value is a boolean value which will hide a button based on what is returned by the url.

This is what I have. It doesn't actually hide the button though. Am I calling the url correctly?

```
function canCreate() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Govern/Initiative/HasPermission',
        success: function (data) {
            if (widows.project.isSuccessful(data)) {

                if (data) {
                    $page.find('a').hide();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is `data` in `success` and what does the code for `isSuccessful` look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try a fully implemented ajax call:

```
function canCreate(url, data) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            timeout: 5000,
            data: data,
            error: function(err){
                console.log(err);
                callback( "Content load failure: "+ url);
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log('get success: '+url);
                //although i think your problem is most likely here
                //make sure you are getting the right data["key"] value
                if (widows.project.isSuccessful(data)) {
                    if (data) {
                       $page.find('a').hide();
                   }
                }
            }
        });
}
```